Is there a way to not have URLs in Excel Spreadsheet table as hyperlinks when using pandas and xlsxwriter?
I made a function to create a table with the contents from the DataFrame to the Excel spreadsheet.
def make_table(file: str, df_to_use: pd.DataFrame):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine="xlsxwriter", datetime_format='m/d/yyyy')
    df_to_use.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    max_row, max_col = df_to_use.shape
    column_settings = []
    for header in df_to_use.columns:
        column_settings.append({'header': header})
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 24)
    writer.close()

The problem is that in the new Excel Spreadsheet, the URLs with http:// and https:// are hyperlinked. This was not the case in the old Excel Spreadsheet where I am getting the DataFrame from. Is it possible to, when making a table with the function above, have the URLs not be hyperlinked or not formatted as an URL?
I did try making a workbook with writer.book and use add_format function but they do not have an option/format for something like 'strings_to_urls' as False.

Using pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine="xlsxwriter", datetime_format="m/d/yyyy", engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_urls": False}}), you should get plain text (like in the original spreadsheet).

Thank you! That is what I was looking for!
